# Why cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was doing a simple task. I am learning Javascript. I have a simple array and I want to call it or appear the info as a card.

**robots.js**

```
export const robots = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org'
  },
  { 
    id: 5,
    name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
    username: 'Kamren',
    email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca'
  }, 
];
```

**card.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Card =(props)=>{
    const {name,email,id}=props;
    
    return( 
    
        <div className='tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5'>
        <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?200*200`}/>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{email}</p>
        </div>      
        );
}
export default Card;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import 'tachyons';
import { robots } from './robots';


ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
  <Card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email}/>
  <Card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email} />
  <Card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email} />
   </div>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

It compiles successfully but output says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

What should I do?

Comment: there is a problem importing robots .. could. you console it ?

Comment: are those files in the same folder? nothing seems to be wrong with the code

Comment: @Mwnawer ,,yeap sir,they are in the same folder...

Comment: that's. working fine !  restart your server

Comment: @Tarik sir did that twice,Restart pc may be the last option then

Comment: I will make a codesandbox for you, just a minute !

Comment: take a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-star-0y708?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LefiTarik thanks a lot sir,thats cleared my confussion.